# How to onclick method set for only one input?

Tags: reactjs, input, onclick, onchange, setstate

First please [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9nmA.png) for SS.

Right now I have 2 input which has value `credit-card` and `paypal`.

I set an onClick event for CreditCard to provide card informations.It works fine but problem is:

Card details doesn`t disappear when I click paypal input. It works just if I click CreditCart input again. I want to make it disappear even I click paypal input. I mean card details should seem only by clicking Credit Card input.

```
class CreditCart extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {show:false};

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
 handleClick () {
    this.setState({ show : !this.state.show})


}
   render () {
    return (
     //2 input here credir-cart has onClick


       {this.state.show && <CreditCart/>


  }
```

Second component which includes cart information part:

```
class CreditCart extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render () {
// information part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleClick` method is wrong. The `setState` method is asynchronous and it will try to execute it in batches which means that the previous value might not be updated yet.

Change it to

```
 handleClick() {
     this.setState(function (prevState, props) {
         return {
             show: !prevState.show
         };
     });
 }
```

See [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: I think I couldn't be understandable enough. Even yours and mine if I click Credit Cart input; informations appear and disappear there's no problem. The thing is after first time info appears, even user click paypal input it has to be disappear.( Kisacasi cart info bilgileri geldikten sonra paypal'a bile tiklansa yok olmasini istiyorum. Ama suan credit cart'a tiklamadigim surece yok olmuyor.)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following should work for you...

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            toggle: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.toggle
                    ? <CreditCardComponent />
                    : <PaypalComponent />}
                <button
                    onClick={e => this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })}
                >
                    Toggle
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```